# UICollectionView single selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How could I implement single selection mode for the UICollectionView class. I need one cell always to be selected but couldn't find a way to disable deselection of the selected cell when tap on it.

I tried to use `shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath` from `UICollectionViewDelegate` but it's never been called.

Comment: Are your other delegate methods called?

Comment: Yep. Other methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (void)deselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to relate to the question being asked